# “Object reference not set to an instance” SPFieldUserValueCollection

Tags: development

I am trying to remove a user from SPFieldUserValueCollection field and I keep getting an error

> Object reference not set to an instance”

Here is my code

```
string userDeleted1 = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.ToString();
SPUser userDeleted2 = sPWeb.SiteUsers[userDeleted1];

SPFieldUserValueCollection Users = (SPFieldUserValueCollection)item[fieldName];
SPFieldUserValue DeletedUserValue = new SPFieldUserValue(sPWeb, userDeleted.ID, userDeleted.Name);
if (DeletedUserValue != null)
{
    Users.Remove(DeletedUserValue);
    item[fieldName] = Users;
    item.Update();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you changed from `userDeleted2` to `userDeleted` in your code.  Try this instead:

```
string userDeleted1 = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.ToString();
SPUser userDeleted2 = sPWeb.SiteUsers[userDeleted1];

SPFieldUserValueCollection Users = (SPFieldUserValueCollection)item[fieldName];
SPFieldUserValue DeletedUserValue = new SPFieldUserValue(sPWeb, userDeleted2.ID, userDeleted2.Name);
if (DeletedUserValue != null)
{
    Users.Remove(DeletedUserValue);
    item[fieldName] = Users;
    item.Update();
}
```